# Unable to display taxonomy attributes in select list

Tags: commerce

I am building a site for a gift seller. Many of his products have attributes which are unique to a given product. But these are too great in number to be bothered creating separate variation types.

The following page from the clients existing site provides a few examples. http://www.peekaboogifts.co.uk/products.asp?p=Scented+%26amp%3B+Novelty+Candles&category=31

What I want to do is have one taxonomy vocabulary called 'free text' which can be used as the main variation type, using an autocomplete widget so that new taxonomy terms can be added easily via the inline entity form.

So far this seems to work for me except for an issue with the product display. For some reason the Attribute selection widget outputs the product title multiple times, instead of the individual variation names. When any of these are selected though, the correct variation is displayed.

Any suggestions of how to correct this?